# Prove: $\det(A)=0$ where $A\in M^{(2k+1)\times(2k+1)}(\mathbb{R})$ is anti-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant

Let $A\in M^{(2k+1)\times(2k+1)}(\mathbb{R})$ where $k$ is a natural number, and also assume that $A$ is an anti-symmetric, meaning

$$A=−A^{T}$$

Prove that $\det(A)=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\det(A)=\det(-A^{T})=(-1)^{2k+1}\det(A^{T})=(-1)^{2k+1}\det(A)=-\det(A)$$
Hence, $\det(A)=0$.