# Why is $\det M$ equal to zero?

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

Let $M$ be a $d \times d$ anti-symmetric matrix, i.e., $M^T = −M$.

Since $\det M = \det(−M^T) = \det (−M) = (−1)^d \det M$,
it follows that $\det M = 0$ if $d$ is odd.

I am not able to understand why is $-\det(M) = 0$.

Or why $\det M = -\det M$ means that $\det M = 0$, meaning $M$ is not invertible.

Comment: If $z$ is a complex number such that $z=-z$, what must $z$ be?

Comment: Im sorry its a mistake, its not given that Matrix M is a complex. It is given that M(2k+1)X(2k+1)

Comment: @Nir: Every real number is a complex number. Every integer is a complex number too. Unless you start considering characteristic 2, the actual field of scalars doesn't matter here.

Comment: x=-x implies 2x=0 therefore x=0

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546086/prove-deta-0-where-a-in-m2k1-times2k1-mathbbr-is-anti-symme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the real or complex numbers, $2x=0$ implies $x=0,$ which is what you need to apply here, with $x=\det M.$

This would only be fail in fields of characteristic $2$, where $1+1=0.$

Answer (score 1):

If you know $\mathrm{det}(M)$, then consider the matrix $-M$: every row has been multiplied by $-1$. Since each time you multiply a row by $-1$ the determinant also gets multiplied by $-1$, this means 
$$\mathrm{det}(-M) = -1^{d}\mathrm{det}(M).$$ 
But you also have that 
$$\mathrm{det}(M) = \mathrm{det}(M^{T})=\mathrm{det}(-M),$$ 
so this tells you that either $-1^d = 1$ or $\mathrm{det}(M) = 0$.